# Find the missing piece

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, visual

One day I got a paper from my courtyard with the center portion missing. Here is what the poster looks like:

[image: pattern with center portion missing]

I have made some pieces of paper so that I can stick one to the center of the poster.

**Here are the pieces.**

[image: pieces that would fit the missing center]

Help me find the best one that will suit the poster. Also, let me know why it will be the best. I will approve the answer with most appropriate justification.

Comment: This isn't an answer but I [hand drew the puzzle so you can see the squares more easily.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fK4fM.jpg)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The answer is

> #5

because

> `W X`
>  `Y Z`

Comment: Wow, dammit! I thought it'd be much more complicated than that! Well done :-D

Comment: Too fast for me. Beat me again...

Comment: Isn't it trivial to see the solution even without the five suggestions, or is something wrong with my eyes? :)

Comment: @jarnbjo when I hold my phone at arm's length, it gets pretty easy to see the solution, but any closer and the squares seem meaningless.

Comment: I got this answer after about 15 seconds too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with number 3 because it almost matches the pattern in the original paper. However, other options also look reasonable.

Edited:
It depends on what you see at the "pattern" in the original diagram. Not everyone sees W, X, Y, and Z as the pattern in the given figure. There is an unique pattern by using number 3 and it looks cool.

Comment: WOW!!! after seeing the solution though, I am amazed...didn't expect the question to be that tricky

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! Would it be possible to edit your answer to expand upon why you believe(d) #3 is the correct answer? Thank you!

Comment: @Emrakul I have edited my answer